# Jenkins build listing unexpected changes in every build

Tags: java, git, jenkins

Jenkins build is listing similar changes as modified in every build along with actual modified files. This is happening only with one repository. The files listed in below image with + icon are the wrong ones.

Kindly help me how to fix it. [image]